# jsoup, ColdFusion 9, Node. "undefined variable" error

Tags: java, coldfusion, jsoup

Okay... I''m trying to isolate, then manipulate text that comes after br tags. I get the output, but an error is thrown. Display code isn't shown below but here's the cfscript block:

```
<cfscript>
jSoupClass = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" );
nodeClass = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.nodes.Node");
textNodeClass = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode");

html = "<html>...</html>";

doc = jSoupClass.parse(html);


brs = doc.select( "table > tbody > tr > td > div > b:last-of-type ~ br");

for( br in brs ){
result = br.nextSibling();
writeOutput(results(result.toString())&"<br />");
}
</cfscript>
```

CF ERROR MESSAGE: Variable RESULTS is undefined.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
writeOutput(results(result.toString())&"<br />");
```

The line above is what's referred to in the Error Message

Comment: The error you are citing does not refer to the code you have posted. The on-screen error message should identify the exact line of code that the error occurred on, including the actual piece of code. Post that.

Comment: The only error the provided code will return (assuming jsoup jar is on classpath) is regarding `results` not existing. When you follow Adam's advice, remember to ensure the code you post is as standalone as possible.

Comment: The error message is correct: `results` is *not* defined in the code you've provided. The line will work as `writeOutput( result.outerhtml() & '<br/>')` but that doesn't do whatever the `results` function is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Peter. I changed the line to what you've provided. I still get the output I want AND the error that I don't want: Variable RESULT is undefined. [referencing the code:writeOutput( result.outerhtml() & '<br/>')].

Comment: I think the issue is due to this line:
result = br.nextSibling(); 
You are never checking if the next sibling is found. If this does not find a sibling this would cause the error you described.

Also results() is not defined in the code above so that is an obvious issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but let me know if I was right.

I'm exploring jSoup and ColdFusion in depth: instead of the `toString()` method, try one of jSoup's `text()`, `html()`, etc., methods.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
for( br in brs ){
result = br.nextSibling();
if(!result.isBlank())
    writeOutput(result.toString() & "<br />");
}
```

You want to make sure you are checking to see if the node is blank or if it has content.